# Lambda expression to fetch two column in a table but how can i access this in my view using viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a lambda expression to fetch two column in a table but how can i access this in my view using viewbag, and what will be the type if we fetch two columns from a table using lambda expression.

Ex:

```
GatesEntities Gates = new GatesEntities();
ViewBag.Index = Gates.Concepts.OrderBy(s => s.concept_id).Select(s => new { s.Concept_Name,s.Session_Id });
return View();
```

I have 5 sessions, in each session i have some concepts. Now I need to fetch concept names for each session in my view using viewbag.

Please help me with this, I wasted lot of time on this..

Comment: Have you tried `ViewBag.Index.Concept_Name` and  `ViewBag.Index.Session_Id`?

Comment: have you tried not storing an anonymous type in ViewBag?  it's like 6 lines of code to create a viewmodel for 2 fields

Comment: you'd be better off setting `ViewBag.Index = Gates.Concepts.OrderBy(s => s.concept_id);`  then you can at least cast ViewBag.Index back to `IEnumerable<GatesEntities.Concepts>`

Comment: I would suggest not using ViewBag. Create a view model, store the two fields into that model and pass the model to your view.
return View(model);  Here is a good article about using models vs viewbag: http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/12/asp-net-mvc-viewbag-is-bad/

Comment: @JDupont- for that reason in my answser i suggest make use of tuple type atles it strongly type if do not want to create special viewmodle to only spport one view ...

Comment: is that answer work for you or helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Viewbag.Index is an IEnumerable(because Gates.Concepts.OrderBy(`s => s.concept_id).Select(s => new { s.Concept_Name,s.Session_Id })` returns a collection), so iterate over it on the view.

```
 @foreach(Concept i in (IEnumerable<Concept>)Viewbag.Index){
       <p>@i.Concept_Name</p>
       <p>@i.Session_Id</p>
    }
```

Comment: I get this error:object' does not contain a definition for 'Concept_Name'

Answer (score 0):

```
GatesEntities Gates = new GatesEntities();
ViewBag.Index = Gates.Concepts.OrderBy(s => s.concept_id).ToList();
return View();
```

View code

```
@foreach(var c in (List<Concepts>)ViewBag.Index)
{
    @c.Concept_Name
}
```

Comment: I already done this way, here it takes time because my whole concepts table is fetched and assigned to viewbag. I need to select just two columns and in my view show concepts session wise.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `new { ... }` means you're creating what's referred to as an "anonymous object". These are typed as `object` and require that you reference the properties inside "dynamically", which is to say at runtime.

As a result, it's a *really* bad idea to use this for things like views, where you're only getting runtime compilation to begin with. At least in something like a controller action, you'll get a bit of compile-time error checking, but in views this is just a time-bomb waiting to explode.

Classes are cheap, and if you're going to do something like this is far preferable to create a class to hold the values as then you'll be strongly-type the whole way through. That means less errors as Visual Studio will properly scream at you as you're writing the code and compile-time errors if you make a mistake anyways. For example (guessing at your types here):

```
public class ConceptViewModel
{
    public string Concept_Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Session_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var model = Gates.Concepts.OrderBy(s => s.concept_id).Select(s => new ConceptViewModel {
    Concept_Name = s.Concept_Name,
    Session_Id = s.Session_Id
});

return View(model);
```

And finally in your view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<ConceptViewModel>

 // whatever
```

Comment: Error: The entity or complex type 'GatesModel.Concept' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.